# Не получается нарисовать значок воспроизведение по центру div'a

Tags: css

Сам div:

```
<div ng-repeat="img in imageList" class="grid-layout video" style="width:166px; 
    height:175px; 
    margin-right:0px;
    background-image:url(http://cs604326.vk.me/v604326802/1a4c8/Pfzm3ka6hK8.jpg);">
</div>
```

Его CSS:

```
.grid-layout {
    display: inline-block; 
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Стили отчасти прописаны прямо в в div т.к. он генерируется JS'ом.

Нужно в центре этого дива нарисовать значок воспроизведения. Я попытался написать стиль:

```
.grid-layout.video:before {
    content: '\25B6';
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
}
```

Но поместить его в центр так и не получилось.

Comment: `.grid-layout.video:before {line-height:175px}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.grid-layout{
   position: relative;
}
.grid-layout.video:before {
    content: '\25B6';
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    background: #fff;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-layout video" style="width:166px; 
    height:175px; 
    margin-right:0px;
    background-image:url(http://cs604326.vk.me/v604326802/1a4c8/Pfzm3ka6hK8.jpg);"></div>
```